# RabbitMq consume aysnc

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, rabbitmq, event-handling

I need to have an async consumer method to consume messages from RabbitMq. My problem is that the rabbitmq client for .net rely on an event handler.
I tried to implement a blocking system with a Semaphore, which is working with a low volume. When I'm getting more volume, some messages are lost.

Here is my implementation :

```
    private long _lock;
    private string _message;
    private object _tag;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _signal;

    public void Configure()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lock, 0);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        consumer.Received += (sender, ea) =>
        {
            _message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body.ToArray());
            _tag = ea.DeliveryTag;
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lock, 1);
            _signal.Release();
        };

        _channel.BasicConsume(queue: _rabbitConfig.Queue, autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
    }
    
    public async Task<string> Consume(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (0 == Interlocked.Read(ref _lock))
        {
            await _signal.WaitAsync();
        }
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lock, 0);
        return _message;
    }
```

I alse tried using BufferBlock but some messages are still lost.
Is there any other way to implement a system keeping my Consume() method ?

Comment: Put received messages in queue, then in consume pop last message in queue (use thread safe queue of course).

Comment: I've tried that, but if i'm not consumming my messages fast enough, my queue will increase indefinitely or i'll loose some messages again

Comment: You can use bounded concurrent collection (`BlockingCollection` class, passing upper bound to constructor). Then code adding item to your queue will block if there are X items there already, and so you will not overconsume from rabbit queue

Comment: https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/asynchronous-rabbitmq-consumers-in-net/

Comment: Hello, I am a primary maintainer of the RabbitMQ .NET client library. I am happy to assist you, but you must first make it easy for me to do so. Please provide a git repository that I can *clone, compile, and run* to see the issue you are reporting. I can then fork that repository and make changes that you can then incorporate. Thank you. In the future, if you have issues with this library, start a discussion [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/discussions).